# How to change Teamviewer ID after cloning

Tags: 13.10, teamviewer

Today I was cloning a couple of images of Ubuntu to further expand the use of Ubuntu over the company but just noticed that all cloned PCs have the same Teamviewer ID. I followed teamviewer forum suggestion about purging teamviewer, removing the .config/teamviewer9 folder and even the /opt/teamviewer one with no luck. The ID stays the same even after rebooting or waiting for about 30 mins before installing teamviewer again.

How can I reset/change the Teamviewer ID in Ubuntu for all the cloned computers. Right now I am using the latest version of Teamviewer (Version 9).

Comment: You made sure to stop the Daemon before deleting /opt/teamviewer9/config right?

Comment: Yes of course. Still the problem was there.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado have you tried to change mac addresses ?

Comment: @kamil no. Will try tomorrow when I get to work and see if that helps although that would be a very extreme step to take to do something as reset a unique ID for an app like this (Teamviewer missing feature maybe?).

Comment: @LuisAlvarado any news ?

Comment: @kamil hi sorry for the delay. Yes it worked after that. It also worked formatting the whole computer because this is what happened after 14.04 arrived ;). You can post it as an answer and I will accept it. Teamviewer team should really fix this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the **MAC Addresses** for Cloned PCs

TeamViewer ID depends on it for sure.

Comment: Verified to work with Teamviewer 9, even without deleting any other configuration files.

Comment: How do I change MAC Address ?

Answer (score 8):

Close TeamViewer. Then run in the terminal:

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon stop
sudo rm -f /opt/teamviewer9/config/global.conf
sudo teamviewer --daemon start
```

Edit: I checked, and TeamViewer also looks at your MAC address. It probably works like this. When you first start TeamViewer (with no configuration files available), it looks up your MAC address. If it is not known by TV, it creates a new TeamViewer ID and associates your MAC address with it. If the MAC address is known, you get the teamviewer ID associated with it.

So, if you clone to a new computer, the commands above would help you get a new ID. If you use them on the original computer, you'll get the same ID.

Comment: I firts it would seem this would fix that problem, even with the variables inside the file, but actually after deleting the whole config file in both, the opt folder and on the .config folder, the problem is the same. I am guessing this should be something the teamviewer team should check out for cases where one wants to clone and have a quick way of solving it.

Comment: this works for me on Ubuntu 20.04; thank you

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous suggestions worked in my case.
The quickest and most effective solution I found was to re-install TeamViewer fresh (after uninstall and deletion of config files in Library/Preferences) from an alternative new user account, that solved it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Please close TeamViewer on the new / cloned machine - then run the following commands in the terminal:

```
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.Machine.plist
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist

rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist
rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.Machine.plist
sudo rm -f /Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is:

Modify /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:

```
[Unit]
Description = TeamViewer remote control daemon
After = NetworkManager-wait-online.service network.target network-online.target dbus.service
Wants = NetworkManager-wait-online.service network-online.target
Requires = dbus.service

[Service]
Type = forking
PIDFile = /var/run/teamviewerd.pid
ExecStartPre= /sbin/ifconfig eth0 hw ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
ExecStart = /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d
ExecStartPost = /usr/local/sbin/restoremac.sh
Restart = on-abort
StartLimitInterval = 60
StartLimitBurst = 10

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Replacing eth0 with your interface and aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff with a new MAC.

Create a script cat /usr/local/sbin/restoremac.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sleep 2
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 hw ether ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa
```

Replacing eth0 with your interface and ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa with original MAC.

Use "chmod 755 /usr/local/sbin/restoremac.sh"

Delete /etc/teamviewer/global.conf

Restart machine

You can keep your MAC and change TeamViewr ID.

If you using teamviewer for personal use only, and you have message "Commercial Use Suspected", this solve the problem!

IF YOU USE IT ONLY FOR NOT COMMERCIAL SCOPE!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the simplest way to change the ID is to change the MAC address of the NIC. This assumes the cloned machine doesn't require the same MAC address. When the server is restarted

Comment: This looks like a partial answer... please [edit] and complete...  **;-)**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)